# Imagemagick & GD vulnerability Issue

Tags: php, laravel, imagemagick, gd, imagick

I'm using PHP Laravel Intervention for image processing, and I heard imagick is better than GD in term of image quality and processing speed. But I read about imagetragick which is vulnerabilities for imagemagick. I'm wondering if the issue is fixed yet on the latest update of version 7? Should I go with GD for safer alternative?

Would appreciate any input.

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of vulnerabilities have you found out? Please share.

Comment: You can find it here: https://imagetragick.com/

Comment: I don't want to click that link, can you put in your question so the information backs up your question please?

Comment: @James Good idea.

Comment: gd library can also be vulnerable.. Image Steganography can be used to make cross site attacks and images can contain PHP payloads..

Comment: Most of the so called vulnerabilities were because no one was setting limits in the Imagemagick policy.xml file. So they never configured it to prevent the problems. The policy.xml file has been there for a long time. If you set it properly, you should not have issue of vulnerabilities.   The latest version of Imagemagick should be as even more safe as other issues have been fixed by lots of "fuzzing" tests.

Comment: @james You can google "imagetragick" and see there's a lot news regarding that. TLDR: There are multiple vulnerabilities in ImageMagick, a package commonly used by web services to process images. One of the vulnerabilities can lead to remote code execution (RCE) if you process user submitted images. The exploit for this vulnerability is being used in the wild.

Comment: @Ren What images are you manipulation - your own or user uploaded ones. You can do different things to validate uploaded images. Save them in a folder that will not run php. Try some online searches for things to do. You mention Imagick and I believe it is more secure than exec() and Imagemagick but you better look into that.

Comment: `@ren` Those article about ImageTragick are flawed because the people never engaged the security prevention policies in the Imagemagick policy.xml file. See https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php for the policy.xml file and its locations. Open the file and read its instructions.